# File reader finding exception

Tags: java, parsing, integer, filereader

**EDIT: Sorry, I'm an idiot. I didn't realize my loop was going for too long for my test documents data, the final product will be 150 lines long, but mine was only 9, causing the error. Sorry for the time wasting, and thanks for the help**

So I need to write a program that reads in data from a file, said data is separated by "," which I am using the split command to store in an array. Every 3rd result is in an integer and needs to be parsed as such, but then I encounter an exception. My code specifically..

```
try {
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.txt"));
    String file = read.readLine();
    String[] store=file.split(",");

    for (int i=2; i<150; i=i+3){               
        int result=Integer.parseInt(store[i]);
            if (result>highresult){
                highresult = result;
                fName = store[i - 1];
                sName = store[i - 2];        
        }
}
    read.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("File Read Error");
}
```

The exceptions is: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:28)
Java Result: 1

The exception is encountered on the parser inside my for loop, and I cannot for the life of me find the issue. Been staring at it so long I think I'm seeing double. Any ideas whats up with it?

Adding for clearness - the test file itself contains the following data

Name1,Sname1,50,Name2,Sname2,75,Name3,Sname3,100

Testing it with a sysout message shows it collects the data from the array correctly, the issue appears to be when changing every third piece of data, in the array at [2][5][8] (50, 75, 100 in this case) into an integer.

Thank you for your patience, still new to this website.

Comment: sysout the store[i] before parsing to be sure that you have the integer (for debug purpouse - maybe your file does not have the correct format (numbers are decimals with comma as separator?)

Comment: I added a sysout just before the parser and tested it with the counter, and it reads the data correctly at the specified location within the array. The test file I created has the follow

Comment: Sorry, continuing from previous - has the follow..
Name1,Sname1,50,Name2,Sname3,75,Name3,Sname3,100

Comment: Avoid putting more infos in comments; update your question instead. And for your underlying problem: you are re-inventing the wheel. So, unless this is some kind of homework exercise, you might want to search net for existing java libraries that do "csv" (comma separated value) parsing for you. This sounds like a trivial task to do; but be assured: if you are talking about "real csv" input (meaning files with 'unknown' content) ... then writing a correct CSV parser is **hard**. You will make a **lot** of mistakes; and hop from one exception to the next.

Comment: Whenever you post a question about an exception, please show us the exception - now we can only guess.

Comment: 'I encounter an exception" is not a problem description. Try again.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn debugging. An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means your index to access the array is not in the range of the actual array boundaries. In your code you assume your array has at least 150 elements. But is this always the case? There is no check for the actual array length. This kind of bug is easy to find with a debugger and a very good example to learn debugging techniques.

Answer (score 0):

well I can see 2 problems: either store[i] is not an int, either you want to get a value out of the bounds of the array

just print out the i before parsing and take a look at its value and if it's <150 take a look at its value in the file

Comment: Done as asked, and both values come out correctly, [I] comes out in intervals of 3, starting a 2, as expected, and the values printed out from the file come out correctly as well. It just doesn't like parsing the integers from the string.

Comment: but what is the last "i" that is printed out? because ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException comes at situtations like this: if your array has max 150 elements, you can't get the 151th or the 152th element because it doesn't exist; and as I'm reading your code it will mots likely try to get the 151th or 152th element from the array